# Self-compiled .deb package and apt-get upgrade

Tags: server, apt

I'm currently self compiling the nginx package using the following:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nginx-extras
sudo apt-get install build-essential
apt-get source nginx-extras
cd nginx
<add some custom module here>
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
sudo dpkg -i nginx-extras_1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb
sudo apt-mark hold nginx-extras
```

I do this because I need to install some custom modules - however after running this, `apt-get upgrade` indicates there is an upgrade for nginx that it would apply if `apt-mark hold` were not in effect. I thought I just compiled the latest version, so why does it want to upgrade??

The problem I have here is that I use apticron which sends me an email each day indicating I have unupgraded packages when I in fact do have the latest.

EDIT: Some additional output:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade --simulate
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nginx-extras
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst nginx-extras [1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4] (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates, Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-security [amd64])
Conf nginx-extras (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-updates, Ubuntu:16.04/xenial-security [amd64])
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy nginx-extras
nginx-extras:
  Installed: 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4
  Candidate: 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4
  Version table:
     1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.9.15-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy nginx-core` and `apt-get upgrade --simulate`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster updated question with info

Comment: `nginx-extras` ≠ `nginx-core`. Please supply the correct command output. Also, why do you install one package (`nginx-core`), tell Apt to hold back another (`nginx`) and expect the former to be held back?

Comment: Sorry, please take a look at the revised question. I actually have `nginx-extras` installed (which conflicts with `nginx-core`)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the check with an apt preference.
For example (change release as applicable):
Create in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/nginx-custom`

```
Package: nginx
Pin: release n=yakkety
Pin-Priority: -1

# This will cause nginx to be ignored and use the locally compiled version only
```

I use this technique with a custom `ffmpeg` compilation similar to your `nginx` need.

Comment: I believe this would completely disable updates? I'd still like `apt-get upgrade` to inform me when my self-compiled version is now out-of-date and potentially insecure.