# compiled program overwritten by daily apt upgrade

Tags: apt, mount, exfat

I am hoping to use pmount with an exFAT-formatted drive, and per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pmount/+bug/1524523 I recompiled pmount and now it works, after installing it with dpkg -i.  However the "daily apt upgrade and clean" seems to be reverting /usr/bin/pmount to the old version that doesn't support exfat.

It sounds like I could just `apt remove unattended-upgrades` but is there a more correct way to tell apt that I want this change to stick around?

Comment: put your own pmount somewhere else and create a symlink over the original pmount. That way you can recreate in from whenever you want. Or rename it to pmount2 :)

Comment: will try that; Also it occurred to me that I could fix this by changing the version number during the build, but I'm not sure how to do that correctly and make apt notice it.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [Self-compiled .deb package and apt-get upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/a/899564/178692)

Comment: update I was able to change the version number. All I had to do was add a new paragraph to the changelog under a new number.  Will test it out overnight